# React native: export default App with multiple module wraps

Tags: javascript, react-native, aws-amplify

I Have the following App.js in my react native project:

```
class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
          <ApolloProvider store={store} client={client}>
        <AppWithNavigationState />
        </ApolloProvider>

      );
    }

}
export default App = codePush(App);
```

I am trying to add aws amplify authenticator to my project (https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/blob/master/media/quick_start.md#react-native-development) but the steps tell me to add :

```
export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

^^ How do I do that when I have already codePush wrapped around the App component that I am exporting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:**
The `withAuthenticator` is basically a [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) which takes a component, decorates it (i.e. provide some special props or customizations of sorts) and returns a new component composed of the component you passed in. So in your case if you want multiple HOCs, you can simply say -

```
export default withAuthenticator(codePush(App))
```

This syntax can get potentially nasty from a readability standpoint if you have, say, 5 decorators. It is useful in such cases to use the new decorator syntax. With it you can do neat things like -

```
@mySpecialDecoratorThatDoesNiceThings
@withAuthenticator
@codePush
export default class App extends Component {
...
}
```

If you are using babel, check out this [transform-decorators](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators) babel plugin to make sure decorators are correctly transpiled.

Comment: thnx Sagar! does it matter what order I put the HOC in? if so wouldn't it make more sense to have the codepush component as the highest order?

Comment: It may or may not matter depending on what the HOCs do and what is needed to be exported. If one of your HOCs e.g. `codePush` expects props from `withAuthenticator` then withAuthenticator must be the first HOC you call, but in most general cases it probably should not matter.

Comment: You can also swap out the withAuthenticator() HOC and utilize your own authenticator.  This would be normal to add auth to a component (e.g. login button) or get a custom UI.  Check out my blog at https://shellmonger.com - I wrote about both these cases in Jan'18